# CLI tools/ways for dynamically constructed DOM structure parsing HTML Javascript

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, html, javascript

I'm planning to make a tool which recognizes HTML using DOM structure in CLI. As many sites produce many DOM elements using JavaScript these days, it's becoming difficult to extract information from downloaded static HTML files. Also I want to analyze them automatically by command line scripts like Linux/bash.

And now I'm searching a way to retrieve and manipulate dynamically reconstructed DOM structure after executing JavaScript in HTML files. (Also note I'm searching ways to emulate to call event handlers like click.)

Is there any tool or ways to do that?

Comment: The first thing that immediately springs to mind would be a normal browser. I know firefox [makes this pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314429/). You could work directly with the firefox source, or you could use a GUI scripting language like AutoHotKey to get what you'd want. In Windows you'd probably want to do something with ActiveX controls. Dunno how you'd get that functionality in Linux.

Comment: I think the two places you'll have the most success looking are browsers / browser APIs. My gut tells me finding pre-existing CLI tools which do what you'd want isn't that likely, but I'm not confident enough in that assertion to put anything I'm saying as more than a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know SpiderMonkey (which is the JavaScript engine used in firefox) can execute only JavaScript code, and wonder it is able to read HTML and construct/manipulate DOM. Since I want to execute my script regularly using scheduler (like cron) in a server without GUI environment, I'm afraid GUI's solution does not work for my purpose.